# Using Multiple Forms at the same time in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access

I am developing an access application and I want the user to be able to open several forms simultaneously without the need to close one form to open another. Thus, my question is: can we minimize a form and use another one while keeping the first one open?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Under the options for the current database select 'Overlapping Windows'. You can the use the 'Min Max Buttons' design property of the form to show a minimze button on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use one main form that is unbound with several subforms?
Alternatively, yes, you can use a second form whilst keeping a first form open. If the tables bound to the forms are related then you will need to save the first form record. I'm no expert in VBA but you should be able to use these commands.

```
openform2btn_click()

docmd.runcommand acCmdSaveRecord
docmd.minimise "form1"
docmd.openform "form2", acnormal
```

then use this to restore form 1 when you require:

```
docmd.restore "form1"
```